# Browser is not working in my Blackberry Simulator

Tags: web-services, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on developing Blackberry application using PhoneGap framwork. I have executed the sample app using below link

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks

But browser is not working in my Simulator.I mean if I try to goto Google site I am getting below error

[image]

I tried following steps too
1)I have installed 'BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.2'
2)Run the MDS and Run my application

Even I am getting issue. Please advice!

Device details:
Windows OS,PhoneGap,BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.2,Simulator:9550,BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Widget Configuration Reference:
    http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/15274/
-->

<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
    version="1.0.0.0">

  <name>Corperate Directory</name>
<access subdomains="false" uri="http://www.google.com"/>


  <description>
      A sample application written with Cordova.
  </description>

  <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
  </license>

  <!-- Cordova API -->
  <feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.find" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Address" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Contact" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.widgetcache" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />

  <!-- Cordova API -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home" />
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />

  <!-- Expose access to all URIs, including the file and http protocols -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />

  <icon rim:hover="false" src="resources/icon.png" />
  <icon rim:hover="true" src="resources/icon.png" />

  <rim:loadingScreen backgroundColor="#CFCFCF"
                     foregroundImage="resources/loading_foreground.png"
             onFirstLaunch="true">
    <rim:transitionEffect type="fadeOut" />
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <content src="index.html" />

  <rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
  </rim:permissions>

</widget>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you going to an external site through phonegap? phonegap is created with the purpose of displaying **local** html pages as the UI for an application, not to use as a browser, for that, you can use a browser.

Comment: yes, but my application is webservice based. Need to implement as Blackberry app.In this case network should work to hit the server! To check my network is working I tried to goto Google site. I need help for the same.

Comment: Did you set the proper permissions in the blackberry manifest files?

Comment: Sorry I am not aware.. Can you plz explain more!

Comment: find between your project files a file named "config.xml" and post it's contents in your question.

Comment: I have pasted my Config.xml here.. Plz advice!

Comment: at this point, all there's left is posting your index.html content :)

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to whitelist google.com in your config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" 
    version="1.0.0.0">
<name>commonPitfalls</name>

    <access subdomains="false" uri="http://www.google.com"/>

</widget>
```

From: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Common-BlackBerry-WebWorks-development-pitfalls-that-can-be/ta-p/624712

Alternatively, instead of checking google.com, you could use the connection api that PhoneGap offers:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Or use an xhr to google.com (with the appropriate whitelisting in your config.xml) to see if you get a response that way instead of loading in a page.

Comment: Sorry no luck.. Getting same issue!

Comment: his permission file, as you can see, has whitelisted internet access in the line:  <!-- Expose access to all URIs, including the file and http protocols -->  <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />